# Find the adjoint of the following linear operator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I have the boundary value problem $$xy''=ky$$ $$y(0)=y'(1)=0$$ and want to find the adjoint, so I have

$L=x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-k I$
$$(Lu,v)=(x\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-k u,v)=\int_0^1 v(xu''-k u)dx=$$
$$\int_0^1 vxu''dx-\int_0^1 k uv dx=$$
$$[u'xv]_0^1-\int_0^1 u'(v+v'x)dx-\int_0^1 k uv dx=$$
$$-\int_0^1 u'vdx -\int_0^1 u'v'x -\int_0^1 k uv dx =$$
$$-[uv]_0^1 +\int_0^1 uv'dx -[uv'x]_0^1 +\int_0^1 u(v''x+v')dx-\int_0^1 k uv =$$
$$-u(1)v(1)-u(1)v'(1)+\int_0^1 u(xv''+2v'-k v)dx =-u(1)v(1)-u(1)v'(1)+(u,L^*v)$$

Now I demand $v(1)=0$ and $v'(1)=0$ so that the boundary terms vanish, so the adjoint operator is $$L^*=x \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+2\frac{d}{dx} +kI$$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You have already asked this question one or two days ago and erased it. You should at least mention it... Besides, what I don't understand is that you assume at the beginning $y(0)=0$ and at the end we have $v(1)=0$ ?

Comment: I haven't asked this question before, if it was asked here before I assume a classmate of mine might have asked it since it is a part of a homework assignment given to me and about 150 other students. Now back to the problem, I demand $v(1)=0$ so I can get rid of the term $-u(1)v(1)$, but should I have demanded that the boundaries of the integral vanish? that is $v(0)=0$,$v'(1)=0$